# set custom caller Id to twilio number while making outbound calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

can i set a custom caller Id to my twilio number using client.calls.create function while making an outbound call. for example:

if i use from: {twilio number} it displays the same number as caller id to the recipients what i want is to have caller id with some names as 'demo'.

if yes then what parameter and conditions required and if there is another way(s) to do so please advice me the process. Technology used is nodejs and language is javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caller Name (CNAM) is an out of band data dip handled by the far-end (terminating telephone service provider). It is not set as part of a call (so not set as an attribute of an API call or TwiML `Dial` verb).

You can open a ticket with Twilio Support (under the ? icon in the Twilio Console, Submit a Ticket), to look at changing the CNAM for your Twilio number and CNAM changes are being added in the future to the [Twilio Trust Hub](https://www.twilio.com/blog/introducing-trust-hub-now-in-beta).

How do I edit or remove a CNAM entry?

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051670533-Getting-Started-with-CNAM-Caller-ID